# phone_number method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to write a method named `phone_number` that accepts an array of 10 digits, that returns a string of those numbers in the form of a phone number.

Example:

```
phone_number([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]) #=> returns "(123) 456-7890"
```

This is what I have at the moment, but it does not work:

```
 def phone_number(numbers)
  number = ""
  number << "(#{numbers[0..2].join}) "
  number << "#{numbers[3..5].join}-"
  number << "#{numbers[6..9].join}"
end
```

Comment: This is not a freelance website, show us your attempts and we'll tell you how to fix them.

Comment: No I won't. I don't take your orders.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code-writing service.

Comment: This would be a good question if you were to tell the community where are you stuck. Also, it would be neat if you could tell us what is 'the form of a phone number'.

Comment: sorry. for not to add my attempts . i am new in this site@Anton & sawa & sneftel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def phone_number(numbers)
  number = ""
  number << "(#{numbers[0..2].join}) "
  number << "#{numbers[3..5].join}-"
  number << "#{numbers[6..9].join}"
end

puts phone_number([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Output:

```
(123) 456-7890
```

And this is simpler:

```
def phone_number(numbers)
  "(#{numbers[0..2].join}) #{numbers[3..5].join}-#{numbers[6..9].join}"
end
```

Comment: thanks so much. it was wrong in my last line. i wrote phone_numbar instead of phone_number